# Converting dates into pd.datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with dates in the following formats:

```
December 22, 2013
November 28, 2016
December 21, 2013
etc.
```

Whats the easiest way to convert them to a datetime?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use fomat from [`http://strftime.org/`](http://strftime.org/) for improve performance with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%B %d, %Y')
```

Or:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

---

```
print (df)
        date
0 2013-12-22
1 2016-11-28
2 2013-12-21
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `to_datetime`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ['December 22, 2013', 'November 28, 2016', 'December 21, 2013']})
print( pd.to_datetime(df["date"]) )
```

**Output:**

```
0   2013-12-22
1   2016-11-28
2   2013-12-21
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```